# Standard deviation: When to use which sum-coefficient?

Tags: education, standard-deviation

I'm wondering when to use

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-X_{mean})^2}$

and when to use

$\sigma = \sqrt{\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_{i}-X_{mean})^2}$

which I have both seen in dfferent scenarios in my studys.
Could you please help me to elaborate this?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The first one is when you have a sample, the second is when you have the entire population.

Comment: To elaborate on @BabyDragon's comment, the second one is the definition of the standard deviation, while the first is an estimator.  By this I mean, assume you have a large population and a small sample of the population.  The first expression is a way to use the sample to estimate the standard deviation of the population.  As such, you use it when you only have a sample but you are trying to infer things about the total population.

Comment: The first one is unbiased point estimate if the mean is estimated as averages. The second one is unbiased if the mean is known.

Comment: By the way, many texts (I am not sure if this is universal) the sample standard deviation is called $s$. Moreover, (as I am told) many old books do not make the distinction.

Comment: In practice it makes little difference which formula you use (data sets are typically large enough), but there are still some instructors out there who care.

Comment: @Aaron It's curious that teachers usually assume that everybody knows the difference. Even in some books appears as "it's well known...". It's useful you pointed out the difference in a clear fashion. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The second gives you the average error in your sample, the first gives you the estimated error in the population from the sample. Why divide by $n - 1$ for the population error estimate? Because the sample has $n - 1$ degrees of freedom; you are free to choose one observation in each sample. If this doesn't help then you can think of it as increasing the estimate to account for the fact you've taken a sample which in itself has an error (if you take lots of samples from the population you'd likely get lots of different estimates for the standard deviation).

In reality the difference is often negligible, especially for large samples, and I would suggest if it *does* make a big difference then your sample size is probably too small. Having said that if you are stuck with a small sample then use the first.